# Multiple JOIN conditions with different operators in $lookup stage sub-pipeline MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, left-join

I want to write below query written in postgresql to MongoDB:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN t2 ON (t1.age = t2.old AND t1.name = t2.alias OR t1.age = 24);
```

The above query has 'AND' and 'OR' operation.

The query which has same operator with multiple join condition has equivalent syntax in MongoDB.

Postgresql:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN t2 ON (t1.age = t2.old AND t1.name = t2.alias AND t1.age = 24);
```

MongoDB:

```
db.t1.aggregate([ {$lookup: { 
                             from: "t2",
                             let: {age_field: "$age", name_field: "$name"},
                             pipeline: [ { $match:{ $expr:{ $and:[
                                                             {$eq: [ "$old",  "$$age_field" ]},
                                                             {$eq: [ "$alias", "$$name_field"]},
                                                             {$eq: [ 24, "$$age_field"]}
                                                                 ]}}}
                                       ], 
                             as: "joined_result" }},
                  {$unwind: {path: "$joined_result", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}}
                ])
```

I tried below syntax for query consisting AND and OR but these are NOT working as expected. Please suggest the correct syntax:

```
1. Used Multiple $match stages:

    db.t1.aggregate([ {$lookup: { from: "t2", let: {age_field: "$age", name_field: "$name"},
                    pipeline: [
                             { $match:{ $expr:{ $and:[{ $eq: [ 25,  "$$age_field" ] },{ $eq: [ "arun", "$$name_field" ] }]}} }
                             ,{ $match:{ $expr:{ $or:[{ $eq: [ 24,  "$$age_field" ] }]}} }
                          ],
                    
                     as: "joined_result" }},
              {$unwind: {path: "$joined_result",
              preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
         ])   

2. OR is part of AND:

    db.t1.aggregate([ {$lookup: {  from: "t2",
                    let: {age_field: "$age", name_field: "$name"},
                    pipeline:[{ $match:{ $expr: [ {$and:[
                                         {$eq:["$old","$$age_field" ]},
                                         {$eq:["$alias","$$name_field"]},
                                         {$or: {$eq: [24, "$$age_field"]}}
                                         ]}
                                    ]  }}
                                    ] ,
                     as: "joined_result" }},
              {$unwind: {path: "$joined_result",
              preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
              ])
          
3. Array of expression:

    db.t1.aggregate([ {$lookup: {  from: "t2",
                    let: {age_field: "$age", name_field: "$name"},
                    pipeline:[{ $match:{ $expr:[
                                                {$and:[{$eq:["$old","$$age_field" ]},
                                                       {$eq: ["$alias","$$name_field"]}]},
                                                {$or: {$eq: [24, "$old"]}}]}}
                             ],
                     as: "joined_result" }},
              {$unwind: {path: "$joined_result",
              preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
         ])
```

Answer (score 0):

The query condition

(t1.age = t2.old AND t1.name = t2.alias OR t1.age = 24)

is the same as:

((t1.age = t2.old AND t1.name = t2.alias) OR t1.age = 24)

The SQL AND operator has precedence over the OR operator.

Then the $lookup pipeline’s $match stage can be constructed as follows:

```
db.t1.aggregate([ {$lookup: { 
                from: "t2",
                let: {age_field: "$age", name_field: "$name"},
                pipeline: [ { $match:{ $expr:{ 
                               $or: [
                                    { $and: [
                                          { $eq: [ "$old",  "$$age_field" ] },
                                          { $eq: [ "$alias", "$$name_field" ]}
                                    ]},
                                { $eq: [ 24, "$$age_field"]}
                               ]
                             }
                        }
                }],
                as: "joined_result"
            }},
           {$unwind: {path: "$joined_result", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}}
])
```